# How can polymer put a list of checkboxes in the left panel?

Tags: polymer

I'm trying to learn Polymer and I'm stuck. My goal is to put a list of checkboxes in the drawer panel on the left using core-list (the choices are dynamic, the server sends JSON in the page [no AJAX in this case]). Here's what I have:

```
<core-scaffold>
<core-header-panel navigation fit mode="seamed">
    <core-toolbar>Left Header</core-toolbar>
    <div fit style="overflow:auto;">
        <core-list id="list" data="{{CheckboxList}}" flex multi>
            <template>
                <div class="row {{ {selected: selected} | tokenList }}">
                    <a href="{{model.Link}}">Go</a>
                    List row: {{index}}, Name: {{model.Name}}, Title: {{model.Title}}
                    <input type="checkbox" checked="{{model.Selected}}">
                </div>
            </template>
        </core-list>
    </div>
</core-header-panel>
<div tool>Right Panel Title</div>
<div vertical layout>
   stuff...
</div>
</core-scaffold>
```

The `div` wrapping the list was intended to get rid of the following error, without success:

```
core-list must either be sized or be inside an overflow:auto div that is sized
```

I've wrapped this list every way I can think of to give it a size, and can't seem to shake this error message.

I'm also concerned because the docs said that `core-list` doesn't render the entire list, only a visible view of elements. This is a problem for checkboxes, since this needs to eventually submit a form with the checked values. Is there a way to override this functionality and force it to render the entire list, or is there an alternative to `core-list` that is better suited for repeating elements that must be rendered?

Answer (score 1):

You may try using `style="height:100%"` as a `core-list` attribute. I recall Rob Dodson mentioning that the `core-list` explicitly needs to be given a height. By doing so I could get rid of the error you mentioned. Here is the jsfiddle and snipped:

http://jsfiddle.net/kreide/zt5xmoa9/

```html
<link rel="import" href="http://www.polymer-project.org/components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="http://www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-elements/paper-elements.html">
<link rel="import" href="http://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-elements/core-elements.html">

<polymer-element name="my-element" constructor="" attributes="">
    <template>
        <style>
            .selected {
                background: silver;
        }
        </style>
        <core-scaffold>
            <core-header-panel navigation fit mode="seamed">
                <core-toolbar>Left Header</core-toolbar>
                <div fit style="overflow:auto;">
                    <core-list id="list" data="{{CheckboxList}}" style="height:100%;" flex multi>
                        <template>
                            <div class="row {{ {selected: selected} | tokenList }}">
                                <a href="{{model.Link}}">Go</a>
                                List row: {{index}}, Name: {{model.Name}}, Title: {{model.Title}}
                                <input type="checkbox" checked="{{model.Selected}}">
                            </div>
                        </template>
                    </core-list>
                </div>
            </core-header-panel>
            <div tool>Right Panel Title</div>
            <div vertical layout>
               stuff...
            </div>
        </core-scaffold>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer('my-element', {
            CheckboxList: [{"Name": "1", "Title": "1" }, {"Name": "2", "Title": "2" }, {"Name": "3", "Title": "3" }]
        });
    </script>
</polymer-element>

<my-element></my-element>
```

PS: I have no answer to your last question though, as I am not sure about rendering behaviour of `core-list`. `core-menu` might be an alternative as it is derived from `core-selector` and might act different from `core-list`. But these are just guesses, not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think in response to your last question, you should bind the checkbox's check state to an attribute on the data used to render the `core-list`. This allows the `core-list` to separate its presentation from the state of the values that you keep in the list. Then, you can use that data in your ECMAscript model to perform actions or submit to a URI.

The [demo](https://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-list/demo.html) for `core-list` shows data-binding to a number of different kinds of input elements.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and my solution was pretty simple. For:

```
  <section route="home" id="home">
      <div fit class="div-core-list">
        <core-list data="{{data}}" flex>
          <template>
            <div class="row">
              <div>{{model.name}}</div>
            </div>
          </template>
        </core-list>
      </div> 
  </section>
```

I've used the css code:

```
.div-core-list {
    overflow: auto;
    height: 300px; /* can be any value in px*/
}

core-list {
    height:100%;
}
```

I hope it helps.